# cannot find module 'babel-register' while creating react-router-sitemap

Tags: reactjs, react-router, sitemap, sitemap.xml, babel-register

I'm trying to create a `sitemap.xml` for my react app using `npm react-router-sitemap` but I keep hitting errors in trying to follow the instructions. I created a `router.jsx` file as instructed:

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router";

export default (
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" />
    <Route path="about" />
    <Route path="resources" />
  </Routes>
);
```

Then I made my `sitemap-builder.js` file:

```
require("@babel/register");

const router = require("./router").default;
const Sitemap = require("../").default;

new Sitemap(router).build("mysite.com").save("./sitemap.xml");
```

When I run this script I get this error:

```
/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/parser/index.js:75
    throw err;
    ^

SyntaxError: /Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/src/router.jsx: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (5:3):

  3 |
  4 | export default (
> 5 |   <Routes>
    |   ^
  6 |     <Route path="/" />
  7 |     <Route path="about" />
  8 |     <Route path="resources" />

Add @babel/preset-react (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-react) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-jsx) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
    at instantiate (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:67:32)
    at constructor (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:364:12)
    at Parser.raise (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3364:19)
    at Parser.expectOnePlugin (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3413:18)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11529:18)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11171:23)
    at Parser.parseUpdate (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11153:21)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11127:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10956:61)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10962:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10937:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10895:21)
    at /Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10863:39
    at Parser.allowInAnd (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12640:12)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssignAllowIn (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10863:17)
    at Parser.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11817:28)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11446:23)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11171:23)
    at Parser.parseUpdate (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11153:21)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11127:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10956:61)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10962:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10937:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10895:21)
    at /Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10863:39
    at Parser.allowInAnd (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12635:16)
    at Parser.parseMaybeAssignAllowIn (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10863:17)
    at Parser.parseExportDefaultExpression (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:14171:22)
    at Parser.parseExport (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:14075:25)
    at Parser.parseStatementContent (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:13020:27)
    at Parser.parseStatement (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12917:17)
    at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:13497:25)
    at Parser.parseBlockBody (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:13489:10)
    at Parser.parseProgram (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12832:10)
    at Parser.parseTopLevel (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12822:25)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:14674:10)
    at parse (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:14716:38)
    at parser (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/parser/index.js:41:34)
    at parser.next (<anonymous>)
    at normalizeFile (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/normalize-file.js:66:38)
    at normalizeFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:21:50)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at transform (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:22:41)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)
    at evaluateSync (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/gensync/index.js:251:28)
    at sync (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/gensync/index.js:89:14)
    at stopHiding - secret - don't use this - v1 (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/errors/rewrite-stack-trace.js:47:12)
    at Object.transformSync (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:43:76)
    at exports.transformSync (/Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap/node_modules/@babel/register/lib/worker/transform.js:94:15) {
  code: 'BABEL_PARSE_ERROR',
  reasonCode: 'MissingOneOfPlugins',
  loc: Position { line: 5, column: 2, index: 93 },
  pos: [Getter/Setter],
  missingPlugin: [Getter/Setter]
}
```

This is the layout of my project and where the aforementioned files are located:

```
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── android-chrome-192x192.png
│   ├── android-chrome-512x512.png
│   ├── apple-touch-icon.png
│   ├── favicon-16x16.png
│   ├── favicon-32x32.png
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── manifest.json
│   ├── robots.txt
│   └── site.webmanifest
├── src
│   ├── App.js
│   ├── App.scss
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── footer
│   │   │   ├── index.js
│   │   │   └── style.index.scss
│   │   ├── header
│   │   │   ├── index.js
│   │   │   └── style.index.scss
│   │   └── main
│   │       ├── 404
│   │       │   ├── index.js
│   │       │   ├── notes.txt
│   │       │   └── style.index.scss
│   │       ├── about
│   │       │   ├── index.js
│   │       │   └── style.index.scss
│   │       ├── home
│   │       │   ├── index.js
│   │       │   └── style.index.scss
│   │       ├── index.js
│   │       ├── resources
│   │       │   └── index.js
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── index.scss
    // the important files here
│   ├── router.jsx
│   └── sitemap-builder.js
// file to show this tree lol
└── tree.txt
```

Are the necessary files in the wrong location? Is that why I'm getting this error? The npm instructions didn't exactly say where to place the files although it may have been obvious and I just didn't pick up on it.

My version of `react-router` is `"^6.3.0",` and I'm running `node sitemap-builder.js`

I originally was looking for what I was doing wrong in trying to create a sitemap, but I would also be interested to know the better way to go about doing this. As in, it's very possible I just am going about this the completely wrong way.

Comment: Is `babel-register` installed as a project dependency? If you run `npm list babel-register` from the project root what is the result?

Comment: `react-sitemap@0.1.0 /Users/almoni/Desktop/Code/react-sitemap
└── (empty)`

Comment: Doesn't look like it's installed as a dependency.

Comment: when i downloaded it using `npm install @babel/core @babel/register --save-dev` it didn't help. I'm not sure what to install and where to install it

Comment: Dumb question, is `babel-register` different than `@babel-register`? If you are installing `@babel-register` then shouldn't the import be `require("@babel/register");`? This is what I see in the [babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register).

Comment: that's what I thought, but the npm instructions specifically say `require('babel-register')` with no @

Comment: interesting. when i run `require("@babel/register");` I get this new error: 
` 
3 |
  4 | export default (
> 5 |   <Routes>
    |   ^
  6 |     <Route path="/" />
  7 
` Seems the error is now happening in the `router.jsx` file

Comment: I'm of the opinion that's a typo. Have you tried it with `require("@babel/register");`? Can you edit the post to include what you've tried just now and a more complete error message so it's easier to read? You may just need to declare a `const` variable first, *then* default export it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249708/discussion-between-eddy-and-drew-reese).